# $location.search - cleanup after use

Tags: angularjs

Out team is new to AngularJS, and in our project there is a webpage which contains, say, a button, and when it's clicked, we do this:

`$location.path("/newpage").search({param:value})`

We just want to navigate to another page and pass it some parameters.
It works, but if after that in that second page we do:

`$location.path("/anotherpage")` - the path changes but the parameters remain! Of course I can do `.search({})` after that.

But isn't it ugly - to explicitly clear the `.search` params every time we do a `$location.path`?

I just don't know how experienced developers do that in mature projects, maybe it's considered a recommended practice to clean up `.search` parameters every time we change location, unless in a specific situation which requires preserving them?

Or maybe we should not use `$location` setters at all, and something else instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only answer I received to this moment, it's from #angularjs IRC.
wafflejock says he usually uses ui-router and its states.

So far that may be the thing I am looking for:

1. Like $location stuff, it allows passing parameters (in a state),
2. And it has go() which by default inherits state parameters, but also has transitionTo() which by default does not, so I can just use the latter unless I want to carry forth the state,
3. What is even more important, if I don't pass the inherited parameters and then want to go back where I came from, and that page has some parameters, I would not be able to restore them with $location, but it's possible with $state, as I can just say "transition back to a parent state".

Any other good ideas?